# trying to center html canvas that requires mouse input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making this game from [this online tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-html5-canvas-tile-swapping-puzzle--active-10747). I have centered the game but adding a style tag that adjusts the canvas:

```css
#canvas {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0; 
    margin:auto; 
}
```

It properly centers the puzzle game, however it has now off-centered my mouse position, making it click the tile of the puzzle that is a couple of pixels off, I tried to just get the offset and subtracting it wherever the mouse is, but it doesn't seem accurate, not working well.

Comment: The CSS should have zero effect on the `offsetX` and `offsetY` values for mouse events triggered on the canvas (see https://jsbin.com/zejediqule/edit?html,css,js,output) so.... please show a [mcve] =)

Answer (score 1):

Mouse event properties [`layerX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX) and `layerY` are non standard. Read-only [mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) properties `offsetX` and `offsetY` already contain the (x,y) position of the mouse over the canvas *if* the mouse is over the canvas.

Hence as a start, try inserting a function to record the mouse position such as

```js
function setMousePos(e) {
  if( e.target.tagName == "CANVAS") {
    _mouse.x = e.offsetX;
    _mouse.y = e.offsetY;
  }
}
```

and replace inlined code

```js
if(e.layerX || e.layerX == 0){
    _mouse.x = e.layerX - _canvas.offsetLeft;
    _mouse.y = e.layerY - _canvas.offsetTop;
}
else if(e.offsetX || e.offsetX == 0){
    _mouse.x = e.offsetX - _canvas.offsetLeft;
    _mouse.y = e.offsetY - _canvas.offsetTop;
}
```

wherever it occurs with `setMousePos(e)`.